# yii2 creating custom based Rest API

Tags: php, rest, yii2, restful-url

I am creating my own custom based action for some calculation, which has to be send by restful api in json. The problem is when i create the controller inherited from activecontroller, then for the index action it asks a model class.

I must need to use index action with my own custom based calculation which does not need to be store in the database so i actually do not need to create model class at all. This is first time i am using activecontroller so i am not sure how to make the index page act as according to my needs.

I am able to create my own custom based action with any name i want  e.g.

```
 public function actionFast()
    {
        echo "XXX";
    }
```

and inside the config/ web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true
            ,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['Apprest/Fast'], 'extraPatterns' => ['GET dast' => 'fast']],
            ],
        ],
```

but instead of my custom "Fast" action i need to use index action for all kinds of calculations. Is there a way to do that?

Secondly i want to make this url restricted for GET only url , is there a way to make send the user to 404 error incase he tries to post on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have model, you can extends right from yii\rest\Controller and add actions that you need

Here you can see example:

```
namespace api\controllers;
use yii\rest\Controller;
class MyController extends Controller
{
public function actionFast()
    {
        echo "XXX";
    }
}
```

Comment: so it means i should create all the error list including 404 etc and also i have to create manually header information since the doc i want to send should be in json format ? Kindly elaborate your answer little bit more

Comment: All things related to rest api implemented in yii\rest\Controller Please look in to source code and you will see. So if you will use this controller you just need to add you actions.

If you will look in to source code of activecontroller, then you will see that this controller extends from  yii\rest\Controller.
And all that it do, just add actions for work with activerecord like index, update ...

so if you want create rest api without active records, you just need extends from rest controller and add your actions

Comment: Here you can see example:
`
namespace api\controllers;
use yii\rest\Controller;
class MyController extends Controller
{
public function actionFast()
    {
        echo "XXX";
    }
}`

Comment: that's right , i did followed and made my own rest controller but the page header mime type still displays html even though i have manually set it to application/json within the controller.